# Dilation about a point (a,b), but not about the origin

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, linear-transformations, transformational-geometry

I recently had a question on a test that asked me to modify the transformation (where r is a scalar of sorts)

$D(x,y) = D(rx,ry)$

so that I could use any arbitrary point $(a,b)$. I am quite sure I didn't do it correctly. I got that for a dilation about the origin

$D(x,y) = (rx,ry)$ by

$$ \left[
  \begin{array}{ c c }
     r & 0 \\
     0 & r
  \end{array} \right]
\left[
  \begin{array}{c}
     x \\
     y
  \end{array} \right]
$$

and also proved that the dilation equation for some $(x_{1},y_{1})$ and $(x_{2},y_{2})$ is
$|r|\sqrt{(x_{1}-x_{2})^2 + (y_{1}-y_{2})^2}$

For any point $(a,b)$, would it be enough to just simply plug in $(a,b)$? Then the new dilation transformation would be

$D(a,b) = D(ra,rb)$ by

$$ \left[
  \begin{array}{ c c }
     r & 0 \\
     0 & r
  \end{array} \right]
\left[
  \begin{array}{c}
     a \\
     b
  \end{array} \right]
$$

I am quite lost at how to go about modifying the original transformation for a dilation about the origin and am sure I am going about this wrong and thus got it wrong in my test. This is for a higher level college math course and again, cannot for the life of me come up with a strategy to figure this out.

Comment: 1) You're not going to be able to write the new dilation as a matrix multiplication. You'll get some more complicated equations. 2) Do you know how to compose transformations? Because you can get the effect you want by 1st) shift the whole plane so (a,b) goes to (0,0), 2nd) do the rotation, and 3rd) shift the whole plane so that (0,0) goes back to (a.b).

Comment: @user275313 I did not think of it that way. Yes I can compose transformations  and have already in other problems came up with the rotation that would come from using (a,b). I will try it out as I would like to figure out the answer. Thank you!

Comment: Okay, And it looks like I goofed and wrote "rotation" when you've been talking about "dilation". (And it's too late for me to edit my previous comment and fix it!) Anyways, for my 2nd step, please read "do the dilation".

Comment: @user275313 That’s not entirely true. The transformation can be expressed as matrix multiplication in homogeneous coordinates.

Comment: @amd how would one go about doing it this way? I am going about the problem as suggested by user275313 and although it is getting a little complicated, I seem to be headed into the right direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, if you have a *linear* transformation $L$, you can create the *affine* transformation $L_{\mathbf p}$ that is “$L$ centered at $\mathbf p$” by translating the origin to $\mathbf p$, applying $L$, and then translating back. That is, $$L_{\mathbf p}(\mathbf v)=L(\mathbf v-\mathbf p)+\mathbf p.$$ Applying this to your dilation with $\mathbf p=(a,b)$ gives us $$D_{(a,b)}(x,y)=(r(x-a)+a,r(y-b)+b).$$

In general, any affine transformation can be decomposed into a linear transformation followed by a translation, i.e., $A(\mathbf v)=L(\mathbf v)+\mathbf t$ for some linear $L$ and fixed vector $\mathbf t$. If $\mathtt M$ is the matrix of $L$, then we can write $A(\mathbf v)$ in matrix form as $$A(\mathbf v) = \left[\begin{array}{c|c}\mathtt M & \mathbf t\end{array}\right]\begin{bmatrix}\mathbf v\\1\end{bmatrix}.$$ This is a simple example of the use of *homogeneous coordinates*. We can apply this idea to get a matrix for $L_{\mathbf p}$. Observe that by linearity $L(\mathbf v-\mathbf p)+\mathbf p=L(\mathbf v)+(\mathbf p-L(\mathbf p))$, therefore the matrix of $L_{\mathbf p}$ is $$\left[\begin{array}{c|c}\mathtt M & \mathbf p-\mathtt M\mathbf p\end{array}\right].$$ Applying this to the dilation produces $$\begin{bmatrix}r&0 & (1-r)a \\ 0&r & (1-r)b\end{bmatrix}.$$ You can verify for yourself that multiplying $(x,y,1)^T$ by this matrix gives the same result as the formula for $D_{(a,b)}$ above.

Comment: See also https://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/fussell/courses/cs384g-fall2011/lectures/lecture07-Affine.pdf for some good examples